# Making custom css for the base @microsoft/fast-components not working

Tags: css, typescript

Making custom css for the base fast-components

I tried to use, as per the docs, putting custom css through when registering the component

```js
provideFASTDesignSystem()
    .register(
        fastButton({ 
            styles: css`
            :host {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              align-items: center;
              max-width: 200px;
              padding: 1em;
            }
          
            button {
              min-width: 100px;
              padding: 0.25em;
              margin: 0.5em;
            }
          `
        })
    )
```

But this code errors with
`Type 'ElementStyles' is not assignable to type 'FoundationElementTemplate<ElementStyles, ButtonOptions>'.`

Any ideas as to why this could be?

Comment: No idea what "base fast-elements" are supposed to be. You should mention/tag whatever framework/library you are using there; just `css` tells is very little.

Comment: Sorry for that, fisrt time posting to stackov, i postetd in the fast-component page and i thought itd add the correct tags. I changed the title but there arent tags for this "framework"

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
const customButtonStyle: FoundationElementTemplate<ElementStyles, ButtonOptions> = 
    (context, definition) => css`
        ${buttonStyles(context, definition)}
        :host { 
            display: flex; 
            flex-direction: column; 
            align-items: center; 
            max-width: 200px; 
            padding: 1em; 
        }

        button {
          min-width: 100px;
          padding: 0.25em;
          margin: 0.5em;
        }
    `;

provideFASTDesignSystem()
    .register(
        fastButton({
            styles: customButtonStyle
        })
    );
```

If you do not want to inherit the styles of the element, then just delete `${buttonStyles(context, definition)}`

You can read more about the problem at the link https://github.com/microsoft/fast/issues/5047